# Safari display: none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

Safari just doesn't open element if I hide it using css property `display: none`! It works in all other browsers though.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="f" class="btn">Select Image</div>
<input type="file" id="file" style="display:none;" name='athletes_imageid'  value="" />
```

Now in my jquery I want to open the `id="file"` by clicking on that "Select Image" `<div>`:

```
$("#f").click(function() {
    $("#file").click();
});
```

Comment: Does `#f` have any height? Try giving it some height

Comment: use `style="height:10px"` attribute on `div#f`

Comment: @VivekKumarBansal this doesn't solve a thing, I can use `visibility: hidden` but not `display: none` in Safari

Answer (score 3):

You can just remove `display:none` and add the following CSS which is the simplest and most cross-browser way I know to do the trick :

```
#file {
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
```

I don't provide you the jsfiddle as it seems not to support my safari version anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

Set type='hidden' don't use a style.

**EDIT: **

Try:

```
#file {
   height: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
   width: 0;
}
```

Comment: He is trying open a file dialog

Comment: I can't do that, my input opens a file selection window for upload.

Comment: Ah, you can try visibility: hidden instead and set a height and width of 0 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<div id="f" class="btn">Select Image
    <input type="file" class="file" name='athletes_imageid'  value="" />
</div>
```

for styles

```
.btn{
    position: relative;
}
.file{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: You know you can overwrite the margin. Right?

Comment: It wasn't a margin in the CSS meaning of it, but I just retried and it was gone, so my fault sorry (I delete the useless comment)